# how to call this function from js?

Tags: jquery, html

The js function is automatically called when submit button is
clicked..ie,by using submit's id my question is how to call this
function from another js function.. Please look at the function i have
to call.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#modalLink').modal({              //id of submit is modallink
        trigger: '#modalLink',        //modal is a function of a js plugin
        overlay:'div.overlay',  
 });
});
```

the html for submit is given below

```
<input type="submit" id="modalLink" onclick="myfunction()" />
```

it is through `myfunction()` i have to call that function..

Comment: What is `modal()`?  That's not part of the jQuery core.

Comment: What function are you talking about? The function passed as a "ready" handler?

Comment: function modal inside ready handler..

Comment: @George: So, what *exactly* do you want to do?  I'm a little confused.  You're saying "is automatically called"... do you not want that?  What do you want `myfunction` to do?  Call the `.modal()` like you have?  Open the modal dialog?  What is `modal()` anyway?  What are the docs for it?  Have you read them?

Comment: modal function is a settings script for popeasy js plugin. the modal function fires when submit button is clicked(by id).but i need to call modal function from myfunction,not button click..

Comment: @George: What do you mean by "call modal function"?  You want `myfunction` to open the modal instead of when the submit button is clicked?  P.S. Do you have a link for "popeasy js"?

Comment: yes,i need myfunction to open the modal instead of the submit button click.submit button click triggers myfunction which opens modal(),pls check http://thomasgrauer.com/popeasy/ for plugin details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to trigger a #modalLink click programatically, if it is accessible, and then it will handle the modal opening for you.

eg:

```
var SomeFunction = function(){
     $('#modalLink').trigger("click");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#modalLink').click(function() {
        $(this).modal({
            trigger: '#modalLink',      
            overlay:'div.overlay',  
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: the button click triggers $('#modalLink').modal() function.what difference does your answer make??